# Eclipse debugger runs wrong version of code

Tags: eclipse

I copied an Eclipse Java project and tried to run the debugger on the copied version. The debugger used the code of the old project. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Have you tried updating the project with F5 ?

Comment: Thanks aleroot for your answer, but Ive already tried.

Comment: This isn't specific. What do you mean, 'copied'? Copied java files? Copied an entire project inside the IDE?

Comment: I copied the entire project in the IDE.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at the launch configuration that you are using to start the debugger. In the Package/Project explorer, do right-click `Debug As..` and then select `Debug Configurations` and make sure all of the details of the launch configuration you are using line up with your new project.

Comment: Ok, your advice leaded me to the solution, to delete the original project from the listed debug configs - now it works. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up at this question after searching for a slightly different problem. Eclipse couldn't find the attached source for some code I was debugging, and I accidentally selected the wrong target in the "Source Attachment Configuration" dialog box. The "Source" tab under Debug Configurations was the place to undo that mistake and set the proper location.

Answer (score 8):

Right-click on the top frame in the debugger's stack view, and select "Edit source lookup...". Remove the incorrect source entry from the list, and/or add the correct one.

Comment: where is this stack view exactly?

Comment: It shows up in the debug perspective when you are debugging code and execution is paused. It shows the execution stack.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to link your server project src folder to your current project.

This could be done as follows:

Right click on project B --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Source --> Link Source --> Browse, then locate the A project src. Finally change the Folder name field as you wish.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Going into the Debug Configurations as per Francis Upton's answer it all looked fine, but I still had the same problem.

Restarting Eclipse fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I have 2 project (A and B) that is referring different version of C. Say A is referring C version 1, and B is referring C version 2. When I am debugging A, C version 2 's source came up always, not C version 1. I ends up adjust the order in debug configuration by remove project B and re-add it. I made project A ahead of project B. That solves the problem.