# Debugging Android in Eclipse - 'step-into' jumps to wrong line number

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I'm using the debugger in Eclipse to trace the execution of a an Android App, however when I try to step-into, either an Android or a Java, class the debugger doesn't step-into the correct method.

I'm using the following code:

```
String irlCode = new String("+353");
String fullNumber = irlCode.concat(phoneNoStr);
Log.d(TAG, fullNumber);

Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNoStr));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

When I step-into `irlCode.concat(phoneNoStr);` or `startActivity(callIntent);` the debugger doesn't step-into the correct method.  I does step-into `String.class` in the 1st case and into `Android.class` in the 2nd case, but it never steps-into the correct method, it steps-into a different line of code in either case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the question? Where does the debugger step to?

Comment: irlcode is an string, so if you step-into a method of that object... you'll go to the String code. Are you sure you shouldn't step-over?

Comment: Normally the source code of these libraries is not available so you probably attached it separately. If this source isn't the exact same version as the compiled lib there may be such differences

Comment: Re:Phil, concat(String string) is at line 672 in the String class, the debugger steps-into line 784 - this is outside the concat() method and precludes me from debugging further as I don't know what I'm stepping-through

Comment: Re: Pablo, I'm stepping-into the String class as a test (after stepping-into the Activity class went to the wrong line) and similar to the Activity class stepping-into the String class goes to the wrong line of code

Comment: Re: Michael, yes the source was attached separately, but both the SDK and the sources are API 17 Rev. 1.  I had a similar problem with API 16 & API 15

Answer (score 1):

This means that the code you are running differs from the source code you have.
I think you are using an older version of android to program.
If you check your project properties, are you then using the newest version of android?
Also, this might help you: 
[Eclipse debugger runs wrong version of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695070/eclipse-debugger-runs-wrong-version-of-code)

Comment: Thank you Valentin, the debugger ran API 10, whereas the code was API 17. I appreciate all the responses I've received - I would have stressed-out about this problem all weekend, now I can kick-back.

Comment: @mbm Where do you set the API in the debug configuration I do not see such a control?

Comment: Perhaps this has changed in the meantime as this is thread is more than two years old.