# When debugging my Eclipse plugin, the repository version of the Java file is chosen over my local version

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm in the early stages of creating a new Eclipse plug-in in Eclipse 2019-06.  I created the plug-in using the "Hello World" wizard option and created a debug configuration that successfully launches a secondary workbench for testing.  I can click on my new menu option and step into my new code.

I want to use a modified version of `org.eclipse.jdt.junit.wizards.NewTestCaseWizardPageOne`, so I added the package to my project and edited `NewTestCaseWizardPageOne`.  However, when I try to debug, the debugger asks for a source location.  It seems to want to load the file from the local repository (.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.junit_3.11.400.v20190510-0840.jar), rather than my edited version.  Why is that?

[image: Debugging session]

There must be some kind of classpath problem, but don't versions of files in the project have precedence over those in the dependent plugins?  I've looked at a number of similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695070/eclipse-debugger-runs-wrong-version-of-code), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174550/eclipse-java-debugging-source-not-found)) and other sources, but I haven't yet found the answer.  Please help.

Comment: Note: You can't replace a page in a existing wizard. This isn't going to work.

Comment: @greg-499 - Thanks.  I'm actually just trying to use some of the import-writing functionality and not the GUI.  I'm having problems, but that may be a different question.  :o

Comment: Why are you trying to use the original `org.eclipse.jdt....` package name? You can't easily replace bits of an existing plug-in.

Comment: @greg-499 There is package-private functionality I'm trying to access.  Is the best solution to update the plugin whose functionality I'm trying to use/extend?  BTW, my plug-in is for local use, not for use as a distributed product, so I'm willing to cut corners and accept some kludginess.

Comment: You won't be able to do this. The Eclipse plug-in system will not permit it.

Comment: You can try to create a fragment for org.eclipse.jdt.ui bundle and create your class there

Comment: @Alexander - The package fragment idea looks promising.  I'll try it.  (If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'll give you credit.)

Answer (score 0):

Following Alexander Federov's suggestion, I converted my plugin into a fragment. This was fairly easy to do following the advice from this [StackOverflow page](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673908/eclipse-plugin-fragment).  The main changes were:

- Renamed plugin.xml to fragment.xml and changed the top level xml
  element from plugin to fragment.
- Added a Fragment-Host entry to MANIFEST.MF

The key advantage that this provided is discussed in an Eclipse [Wiki
page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_plug-in_fragment%3F):

> ... a fragment appears much the
>   same as a normal plug-in. A fragment can specify libraries,
>   extensions, and other files. When it is loaded by the platform loader,
>   a fragment is logically, but not physically, merged into the host
>   plug-in. The end result is exactly the same as if the fragment's
>   manifest were copied into the plug-in manifest, and all the files in
>   the fragment directory appear as if they were located in the plug-in's
>   install directory. Thus, a runtime library supplied by a fragment
>   appears on the classpath of its host plug-in. In fact, a Java class in
>   a fragment can be in the same package as a class in the host and will
>   even ***have access to package-visible methods on the host's classes***.

The last part having to do with access to package-visible methods was what I needed.  Thanks, Alexander!